# AutoIncrement PK incrementing irregularry

Tags: mysql, laravel

I recently release an app: https://my.kendozone.com in Laravel 5.3 / MySQL

I'm getting users, but one weird thing is that my user's id are not incrementing by one.

HERE  last 10 rows id :

```
5401
5402
5403
5404
5405
5406
5407
5408
8359
9799
```

The 2 ways I save my users are :

```
$user = User::create([
                'provider' => $provider,
                'provider_id' => $userData->id,
                'name' => $userData->name,
                'firstname' => $userData->name,
                'slug' => str_slug($userData->name),
                'email' => $userData->email,
                'avatar' => $avatar,
                'role_id' => config('constants.ROLE_USER'),
                'verified' => 1,
            ]);
```

or

```
$user = User::create(['name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
            'role_id' => config('constants.ROLE_USER'),
            'verified' => 1,

        ]);
```

How should understand this??? Is it normal???

Does anybody have an explanation???

Comment: Do you delete any records from the users table?

Comment: yes, but not in this case. I am the only user that can delete users, and I did not delete any lately...

Comment: Is it possible that you are accidentally setting the value of the id column when creating a new user? e.g. User::create(['id' => 12345, 'email' => 'something@email.com']);

Comment: I doubled checked, and there is only 2 ways that I create a user, none of them have id inside. Check updated question. Beside, I never delete users, I always soft delete them

Comment: Read your logs.  One possibility: you have someone trying to create acccounts with usernames that already exist.  If your code encounters a duplicate unique key error during insert, thr auto_increment value used by the next row will increment itself.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE...` will show you the next auto-increment value.  Watch it, and if it changes without users being added, you know that whatever it is, it happened recently.

Answer (score 0):

My id are weird because of my Functional tests.

when running, they use :

```
use DatabaseTransactions
```

that mean that all queries runs into a Transaction, but I guess it uses ids range.